# How to notify navigation controller it should push a viewcontroller, from a subview of n layers?

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols, nsnotificationcenter

I have a view that I want to reuse in different situations.  It is a user view that, when touched, will have the viewcontroller push a user detail viewcontroller.

So basically I have a view that can any number of superviews until the viewcontroller.  I want that view to be able to notify whatever viewcontroller that is currently being displayed to push the user detail view.

Is there a way besides using `NSNotificationCenter` to do this?  Is `NSNotificationCenter` my best option?  I've tried to put in a protocol/delegate, but that isn't working out for me.

Thanks!

------------------------Response to a comment----------------

I would like to have it so it is dynamic.  That is partially my problem.  I will use this view throughout my code and when I make updates/changes, I don't want to have to change the actual user view to make things work

An example would be adding this user view on the following hierarchy: viewcontroller->tableview->tableviewcell->userview.  But then I'd also like to add it like this: viewcontroller->userview.

Comment: it would help to see the code that creates the view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

`navigationController.topViewController` may be helpful in this case. Or if your app is using a single navigation stack, you could handle this notification in the appDelegate

```
@interface AppDelegate
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *nav;
...
[nav pushViewController:userVC animated:YES];
```

I think it does make sense to use an NSNotification in this case. Per MVC, the UIView handling the touch event should not need to know much about the View Controller hierarchy it lives in. Notifications handle that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that I will subclass a `UINavigationController` and register for my `NSNotification` there, then i won't have to worry about registering on each `UIViewController` in my app.  I'll leave this answer here for a bit without checking it as the answer to see what kind of side effects this might have.